# Visual Studio Online / Azure stopping and starting web applications using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online's build tools to deploy web applications from a single solution. I've occasionally been running into file locking issues.

> Error: Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.

After some Googling, I believe the "fix" is to stop the web applications before deployment on Azure and start it back up after. Sounds legit.

However, there does not seem to be a straight forward way to do this directly on VSO's build definitions. I've created an "Azure Powershell" build task, but it wants a PS1 file from the repository. It doesn't seem to let me just run Azure Powershell commands (e.g. Stop-AzureWebsite) from here. My team has created a work-around where we have a "run.ps1" that just executes the command you pass as a parameter, but none of us are satisfied by that.

What are we missing? There has got to be an easier way to do this without having a PS1 script checked into source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by installing [Azure App Services - Start and Stop extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbengtsson.appservices-start-stop) from Visual Studio Marketplace.
When installed, it will allow you to wrap the `Deploy Website to Azure` task in your Release definition with `Azure AppServices Stop` and `Azure AppServices Start` tasks, effectively eliminating the lock issues.

[image: VSO Release tasks]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't validate this easily as we've moved to a Jenkins server =/. This looks legit though, so I'll mark this answered. When I looked, the extension only had 3/5 stars but it looks fairly new too. Hopefully the kinks get worked out soon.

Answer (score 2):

**Check if you are using "/" on the "Web Deploy Package" path  for folder separators instead of "\".**

i.e. change

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/My Project/drop/MyFolder/MyFile.zip
```

for

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\My Project\drop\MyFolder\MyFile.zip
```

I noticed that was the only difference between the one I was getting the error and the others (the Restart step I added was not helping). Once I modified the path, I got it working.

Sounds crappy, but fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the Build Deployment Template that sets the correct msbuild parameters for you for your package?  You can see how [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/aspnet4). I would create a build using that template and see if you have the same issues.  If so ping me on Twitter [@DonovanBrown](https://twitter.com/donovanbrown) and I will see if I can figure what is going on.

Comment: Yes, but lately this project has been plagued with this error on Azure deploys: 

##[error]Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.
 
##[error]  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.

Comment: As a side note, I really don't want to have to have Azure deployment information checked in the project's source control (in the form a of Grunt script or something). I'd rather that be isolated to my build definition.

Comment: I also found this link (http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing) regarding the AppOffline rule. Is this something I can pass in the Azure Web App Deployment / Additional Arguements step?

Comment: I will make sure our Build PM is aware.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm trying adding the -DoNotDelete flag on the Azure deployment step as well. I don't think this is the intention of this flag or even if it will have an effect, but hey, it's something to try. Since the problem is somewhat random, I'll post again here if the issue persists.

Comment: @Donovan - I'm also hitting this frequently now too. In this case, it's happening as part of the RM pipeline

Comment: @Donovan this is still happening (well, I'm getting this one: "Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process."). What is interesting, is I have two environments on RM, one for Dev on North Central US, and a second one for QA on West US. The problem only appears on West US.

Comment: The [Trackyon Advantage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Trackyon.trackyonadvantage) extension for Team Services has a task to let you stop and start a slot before deploying to it so you have no issues with file locks. You can stop one slot and the rest keep running. You can read about it [here](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2016/06/05/MicrosoftCodeAnalysisCSharpdll-Locked-Problem-Fix).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule it is good practice to have any scripts or commands required to deploy your software to be checked into source control as part of your build. They can then be easily run repeatedly with little configuration at the build level. This provides consistency and transparency.

Even better is to have deployment scripts output as part of the build and use a Release Management tool to control the actual deployment.

Regardless having configuration as code is a mantra that all Dev and Ops teams should live by.

Comment: That is certainly an opinion =)